# Restricted Function with fpc using libsandbox?

Tags: sandbox, fpc

I'm making an online-judge program base on PHP and the problem is when i try to add pascal language, it's always RF. I using libsandbox and framework Yii to make it, I've read many topics about Restricted function and about Free-pascal but nothing change. I'm very tired. This is my compile command for fpc

```
fpc -m32 -XS -o%DEST% %SOURCES%
```

Please help me out.
P/s: I added the C++ language and it worked so I think the problem is not in my php code.

Answer (score 0):

You see to have not studied fpc's switches.  Type *fpc -h* to see valid switches.

1. *-m32* is not a valid Free Pascal switch. The closest equivalent is -Pi386, but it is usually simpler simply installing the 32-bits edition.
2. *-XS* is for special cases and probably redundant (passing -static to ld to link C libraries static, FPC libs are static by default).
3. *-o* is probably also redundant, destination is autoderived from the source name.
4. Only one source file is supported at a time. FPC will autobuild dependencies though.